# Combo de produto e jogar valor em inputText

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf

Estou desenvolvendo uma cadastro de DOCUMENTO com parâmetros como Material, Nome e outros dados. E como vai funcionar, realizo antes um cadastro normal de PRODUTO com parâmetros de Material e Nome e na tela de cadastro do DOCUMENTO quero abrir um combo como esse codigo “Material” e escolhendo ele, será jogado automaticamente o nome no campo inputText DE NOME.

Eu criei o combo e consigo selecionar.

Como realizar essa função, algo do JSF, JavaScript? Me falaram do valueChanceListener, mas tmb não sei como seria?

Tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

::Entidade PRODUTO

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "produto")
public class Produto implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "material", unique = true, length = 5, nullable = false)
private int material;

@IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Nome", campoConsulta = "nome",      principal = 1)
@Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String nome;
```

::Entidade DOCUMENTO

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "documento")
public class Documento implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Código", campoConsulta = "id")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "material", length = 5, nullable = false)
private int material;

@IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Nome", campoConsulta = "nome",      principal = 1)
@Column(name = "nome", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String nome;
```

::TELA E SELECTONEMENU

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridDocCabecalho" columns="14">

<p:outputLabel for="material" value="Material " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="material" filter="true"
    value="#{documentoBeanView.objetoSelecionado.material}"
    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Faltou selecionar o campo obrigatório 'Material'!!">

    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"  itemLabel="Selecione material" />

    <f:selectItems value="#{produtoBeanView.produtos}" var="cursor"
    itemLabel="#{cursor.material}" itemValue="#{cursor.material}" 
    actionListener="documentoBeanView.teste()"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome " />
<p:inputText id="nome" value="Nome " />
```

::Entidade ProdutoBeanView

```
@Controller
@Scope(value="session")
@ManagedBean(name="produtoBeanView")
public class ProdutoBeanView extends BeanManagerViewAbstract {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String url = "/cadastro/cad_produto.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
private String urlFind = "/cadastro/busca/find_produto.jsf?faces-redirect=true";

private Produto objetoSelecionado =  new Produto();

private List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();

@Autowired
private ProdutoController produtoController;

public List<SelectItem> getProduto() throws Exception{      
return produtoController.getListProdutoController();
}
```

Comment: O código retornado no navegador, o HTML.

Comment: Vi que editou a pergunta. Então seria `$(document).on("change", "#material", function(){ $("#nome").val($(":selected", this).text()); });`

Comment: Se quiser enviar o `value`, seria: `$(document).on("change", "#material", function(){ $("#nome").val($(this).val()); });`

Comment: Aí eu não sei dizer pq não entendo de jsf. :D Mas em página comuns isso deveria funcionar.

Comment: @RafaelBlum, front não é meu forte...