# Remover objetos que estão atrelados a lista de outros

Tags: java, jpa, entidade-relacionamento

Estou com uma problema na remoção de um objeto. O que esta acontendo:
Tenho duas tabelas -> PROCEDIMENTO e SETOR:
Posso criar normal os setores, salvar, editar, excluir e adicionar os procedimentos a lista de cada setor criado, até ai OK.

**Mas o problema meu é** que quando vou na tela de procedimentos e faço uma exclusão de algum procedimento que esta na lista de algum setor, ele exclui o setor ou setores que tem o mesmo.

Meu MODEL:::SETOR

```
@NotAudited
@ManyToMany(cascade =  CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="setor_proced",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="procedimento_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="setor_id")})
private List<Procedimento> procedimentos = new ArrayList<Procedimento>();
```

Meu MODEL:::PROCEDIMENTO

```
@IdentificaCampoPesquisa(descricaoCampo = "Setor", campoConsulta = "setor.nome")
@NotAudited
@Basic
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="procedimentos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Setor> setores = new ArrayList<Setor>();
```

BEAN:::Metodo para excluir procedimento

```
@Override
public void excluir() throws Exception {
    objetoSelecionado = (Procedimento) procedimentoController.getSession().get(getClassImplement(), objetoSelecionado.getId());

    //REMOVE DA LISTA DE PROCEDIMENTOS
    procedimentos.remove(objetoSelecionado);

    //REMOVENDO DO BANCO
    procedimentoController.delete(objetoSelecionado);

    novo();
    sucesso();
  }
```

**Tenho que mudar algo no método ou mudar o cascade ou fetch??**

Erro PrintStackTrace:::

```
76587 [http-nio-8085-exec-3] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
76587 [http-nio-8085-exec-3] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gerenciador_fabril`.`setor_proced`, CONSTRAINT `FKD74A5E2FB1E5E9FF` FOREIGN KEY (`setor_id`) REFERENCES `procedimento` (`id`))
jun 01, 2018 4:29:17 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{procedimentoBeanView.excluir()}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
javax.faces.FacesException: #{procedimentoBeanView.excluir()}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at br.com.project.filter.FilterOpenSessionInView.doFilter(FilterOpenSessionInView.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2728)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2911)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.flush(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.framework.implementacao.crud.ImplemantacaoCRUD.executeFlushSession(ImplemantacaoCRUD.java:253)
    at br.com.framework.implementacao.crud.ImplemantacaoCRUD.delete(ImplemantacaoCRUD.java:78)
    at br.com.project.bean.view.ProcedimentoBeanView.excluir(ProcedimentoBeanView.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:80)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gerenciador_fabril`.`setor_proced`, CONSTRAINT `FKD74A5E2FB1E5E9FF` FOREIGN KEY (`setor_id`) REFERENCES `procedimento` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1977)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:4963)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2710)
    ... 98 more

javax.faces.FacesException: #{procedimentoBeanView.excluir()}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at br.com.project.filter.FilterOpenSessionInView.doFilter(FilterOpenSessionInView.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{procedimentoBeanView.excluir()}: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [br.com.project.model.classes.Procedimento#2]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2728)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2911)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.flush(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.framework.implementacao.crud.ImplemantacaoCRUD.executeFlushSession(ImplemantacaoCRUD.java:253)
    at br.com.framework.implementacao.crud.ImplemantacaoCRUD.delete(ImplemantacaoCRUD.java:78)
    at br.com.project.bean.view.ProcedimentoBeanView.excluir(ProcedimentoBeanView.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:80)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gerenciador_fabril`.`setor_proced`, CONSTRAINT `FKD74A5E2FB1E5E9FF` FOREIGN KEY (`setor_id`) REFERENCES `procedimento` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:683)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1977)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:4963)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2710)
    ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim.

Você precisa remover a opção de `cascade` entre `Procedimento` e `Setor`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="procedimentos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Ou alterar ela para o cenário que se adéque mais ao seu caso.

Da forma que está, qualquer alteração em procedimento (criar, alterar ou excluir) vão ser todas propagadas (`CascadeType.ALL`) em cascata para os setores.

Se você quer mudar esta ação apenas para exclusão (para não excluir), mas continuar propagando criação e atualização, você pode usar esta configuração:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="procedimentos", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
```

Após isto, você precisa remover a relação dos setores com este procedimento e remover os setores do procedimento.

```
for (Setor setor : setores) { 
    setor.getProcedimentos().remove(procedimento); 
} 
procedimento.getSetores().clear();
```

Depois você poderá remover o procedimento.

Comment: Ola, Dherik
Teste aqui.
Qual foi meu teste, add procedimento X a um setor e quando na tela de procedimento vou excluir o procedimento X, gera a mensagem de que "não posso excluir por estar associado". Existe a forma de excluir o procedimento direto sem antes ir la no setor e excluir ele?

Comment: Este erro é do seu sistema ou é do Hibernate? Passe o erro do Hibernate.

Comment: É só uma mensagem padrão do JSF que personalizei. Como no banco de dados, quando queremos excluir uma tabela que esta associada a outra.

Comment: Mas você não tem a exception original? É importante imprimir ela no log para entender estes e outros problemas no futuro

Comment: Pensei assim, não sei se seria a forma correta, mas criar um método que quando mando excluir um procedimento x, ele antes busca todos setores e vai excluindo a associação e depois exclui o procedimento no banco. Que achas?

Comment: @RafaelBlum, coloca a stacktrace inteira na sua pergunta. Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o erro todo lá.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78327/discussion-between-dherik-and-rafael-blum).

Comment: pode me ajudar neste poste?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302217/combo-de-produto-e-jogar-valor-em-inputtext